# Matlab convert anonymous function to Latex expression

Tags: matlab, latex, anonymous-function, symbolic-math

I want to pretty print an anonymous function, so I found the function `latex` (which only takes symbolic expressions) to do this:

```
f =@(x,a) (x/a) * exp(-x.^2 / (2*a^2));
latex(sym(f))
```

which outputs:

```
\frac{x\, \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2\, a^2}}}{a}
```

However, the above LaTeX syntax is **not** in the way I originally entered in the function. I would like the LaTeX syntax to appear in the same fashion I originally wrote it out, like the following:

```
\frac{x}{a} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2\, a^2}}
```

I'd also be willing to start with a string. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: To tell Matlab's symbolic engine to output something like it's logical, it's like to tell an old stubborn farmer how to grow his corn. I deal with that on a daily basis... Don't even try.

Comment: The problem does not lie in `latex(...)`, it lies in `sym(...)` which outputs: `(x*exp(-x^2/(2*a^2)))/a`

Comment: So the only option you have is to split your equation in two parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @thewaywewalk points out, an expression converted to symbolic math is "simplified" according to Matlab's rules. Here's an approach to avoid that. First you need to convert your numeric function to a suitable string (get rid of argument list, remove element-wise operators) and then convert it to a symbolic expression while calling MuPAD's [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/hold.html):

```
f = @(x,a) (x/a) * exp(-x.^2 / (2*a^2));
fstr = regexprep(func2str(f), '^@\(.*?\)|\.', '') % Remove arguments, element-wise operators
fsym = feval(symengine, 'hold', fstr)             % Convert to symbolic expression
latex(fsym)
```

This returns:

```
\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\, \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{x^2}{2\, a^2}}
```

which looks like:

[image: LaTeX expression]

I'm not sure how reliable this scheme will be in more complex cases as conversion from math to LateX is ill-defined. If you want particular precise LaTeX expressions (e.g., parentheses in particular places but not others), you'll need to write or edit them yourself or come up with your own conversion function.